# Correct usage of the Windows console API's CHAR_INFO structure

Tags: c++, c, windows, unicode, console

The Windows API part for console functions `wincon.h` defines a data structure `CHAR_INFO` as follows:

```
typedef struct _CHAR_INFO {
    union {
        WCHAR UnicodeChar;
        CHAR AsciiChar;
    } Char;
    WORD Attributes;
} CHAR_INFO, *PCHAR_INFO;
```

So we have a union of an 8-bit and a 16-bit character denoting ASCII and Unicode characters, respectively. Usually, if you have to deal with unions in C, you have tagged unions, i.e. an extra field is present indicating which of the union's fields is being used. This is not the case here (`Attributes` is used for something different), so I'm wondering how to correctly use values of this data type.

If we look at what functions of the API actually use this or similar structures, we find that it's only used by functions that exist in two variants: either suffixed with an `A` (for the ASCII variant), or suffixed with a `W` (for the Unicode variant).

So is it save to assume that the `A` variants of these functions will only use the `AsciiChar` field of this structure, and the `W` variants only the `UnicodeChar` field? If not, how do you know what field is actually being used and how to convert one field into the other? The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms682013(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't seem to say anything about the correct usage here.

Comment: There is neither an 8 bit nor a 16 bit character, unless those all-uppercase homebrew-names are not the same as the types from the standard. Any reason you don't use the standard names, but have some irritating uppercase-versions? And you cannot "tag a union". You have to wrap it into a `struct` (or vice versa).

Comment: Yes, the console api comes in two flavors, based on whether or not you have UNICODE defined.  Yes, the A and W variants.  That stopped mattering about a decade ago, actual implementation is always Unicode.  The A flavor apis translate to the local codepage to produce the AsciiChar variant.  Writing Unicode compatible C or C++ code never happens by accident, you always know when you want to use CHAR_INFO.Char.UnicodeChar.  Bit of a mystery why they didn't use TCHAR or named it AnsiChar btw, there was perhaps a designer behind it that thought it was all a kludge :)

Comment: @Olaf: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. The above stucture is a literal copy of the defintion in the `wincon.h` header file from the Windows API, and the uppercase type names are the convention used by the Windows API which defines `CHAR` to be an 8-bit and `WCHAR` to be a 16-bit character (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)). Also, the union _is_ wrapped into a struct.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I'm very confident at least `char` **did** exist at that time. Actually back then systems with other than 8 byts/byte were much more common than today. Anyway, that still is no excuse not to modernize the API every 15-20 years or so. But what do I say, they apparently are not even able to support a 17 year old language standard.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: `char` was always one byte. You seem to think a byte is the same as an octet. That is wrong. It is not and never has been! I don't know "millions of third-party developers", but I know a lot of developers who scream because of ancient APIs. Note that Apple mad such changes multiple times, including two complete platforms and it went pretty well. Similar other systems. And yes, they mad those changes with ca. the same number of units the WinAPI had when such a change could have been made. But one can try to excuse any wrong decission, this discussion is moot.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It should then have been `BYTE`, if not for anything else but make it clearly disting from `char`. Regarding a byte: As  iwrote, read the standard, and lern about other architectures (sorry, but that is typical DOS/Win/x86-only programmer thinking). The C standard is very clear about this and "byte" never has been the same as an octet (that's why e.g. networking standards/RFCs don't use that term). It is just a common **assumption** of people with experience octet-based machines. For instance, 9 bit/byte were quite common in the 80ies and 16 bit `char` machines are still spread

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It is relevant for the C language, which is not DOS, Windows, etc.! (And `char` has no specific signed-ness. Point is MS messed up things in the WinAPI and did not correct until today. As usual. And fixed-width standard types would have been nonsense in C. How to go with a 9-bit/byte machine in C? Etc. EOD

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It certainly is not. There are still CPUs with other than 8 bit addressing scheme. In retrospect, its flexibility was the reason for the success of C! I'll finally end this here, you might first want to get a broader picture. Get rid of your Scheuklappen.

Comment: @Olaf: seriously, dude, why so aggressive?  Can't we have a difference of opinion without accusing me of being ignorant?  I'll leave this here too, because honestly you're starting to really annoy me, but the bottom line is that Windows needed fixed-width types, and the language didn't provide them.  I'm sorry if the solution Microsoft chose doesn't meet with your approval, but it is what it is and it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is it save to assume that the A variants of these functions will only use the AsciiChar field of this structure, and the W variants only the UnicodeChar field?

Yes.